# How do I get the real annotation instead of a proxy from ConstraintDescriptor::getAnnotation? (javax.validation Apache Bval)

Tags: java, reflection, java-annotations, javax.validation

I'm trying to get a `Class` object reference for the annotation which caused a `ConstraintViolation` in the `javax.validation` package (Apache Bval implementation).

After getting some ConstraintViolations, I pass them into the following function:

```
private Class<?> getConstraintAnnotation(final ConstraintViolation<?> constraintViolation) {
    return constraintViolation
        .getConstraintDescriptor()
        .getAnnotation()
        .getClass();
  }
```

And this returns a class object whose `getName()`, `getCanonicalName()`, and `getTypeName()` all return "java.lang.reflect.Proxy".

Weirdly enough, the `toString()` method of the `Class` object returns back
"class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10".

Is there a way for me to get the real annotation classes and not these proxies? I would ideally like to map the built-in annotations to error codes (without having to overwrite the message every time I use it).

Answer (score 2):

Java annotation is implemented by `Proxy`. The `Proxy` do be the **really** annotation. You should use `Annotation.annotationType` rather than `Object.getClass` to get the real annotation class.